# How to set variable properly in linq DateTime?

Tags: c#

I am new in programming and in C# in general. Recently, I have been making a tool to filter data from csv format. I have found that using `linq` is the best option for me. As you can see, the code posted below this paragraph works well, but I would like to make it more flexible. I would like to ask is there is smarter way to make: `DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, s.Date.Hour, s.Date.Minute, s.Date.Second)` as a variable where user  can select it as an option. Right now, I have wrote code where user selects option and based on the variable: `PublicVariables.customfiltersetting == 5` I am using conditional to set my ordering... Here are the rest of the code:

```cs
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputname))
{
    var ordering = from s in Filter.FullData()
        group s by new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, s.Date.Hour, s.Date.Minute, s.Date.Second)
        into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby g.Key descending
        select new {Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count};

    if (PublicVariables.customfiltersetting == 0)
    {
        ordering = from s in Filter.FullData()
            group s by new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, s.Date.Hour, s.Date.Minute, s.Date.Second)
            into g
            let count = g.Count()
            orderby g.Key descending
            select new {Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count};
    }
    else if (PublicVariables.customfiltersetting == 1)
    {
        ordering = from s in Filter.FullData()
            group s by new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, s.Date.Hour, s.Date.Minute, 0)
            into g
            let count = g.Count()
            orderby g.Key descending
            select new {Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count};
    }
    else if (PublicVariables.customfiltersetting == 2)
    {
        ordering = from s in Filter.FullData()
            group s by new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, s.Date.Hour, 0, 0)
            into g
            let count = g.Count()
            orderby g.Key descending
            select new {Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count};
    }
    else if (PublicVariables.customfiltersetting == 3)
    {
        ordering = from s in Filter.FullData()
            group s by new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, 0, 0, 0)
            into g
            let count = g.Count()
            orderby g.Key descending
            select new {Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count};
    }
    else if (PublicVariables.customfiltersetting == 4)
    {
        ordering = from s in Filter.FullData()
            group s by new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            into g
            let count = g.Count()
            orderby g.Key descending
            select new {Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count};
    }
    else if (PublicVariables.customfiltersetting == 5)
    {
        ordering = from s in Filter.FullData()
            group s by new DateTime(s.Date.Year, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            into g
            let count = g.Count()
            orderby g.Key descending
            select new {Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count};
    }
    else
    {
        ordering = from s in Filter.FullData()
            group s by new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, s.Date.Hour, s.Date.Minute, 0)
            into g
            let count = g.Count()
            orderby g.Key descending
            select new {Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count};
    }

    foreach (var s in ordering)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Date + "\t" + s.Column + "\t " + s.Average + "\t " + s.Count);
        writer.WriteLine("Date: " + strings.Value + " Value: " + strings.Average.ToString("0.00") + "\t" +
                         " Count: " + strings.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: The extension methods for queryables receive queryables and return queryables. Meaning, you can create a base queryable and based on a condition compose the desired queryable.

Comment: You should be able to stuff your DateTime into a variable, and then write and use your Linq query using that DateTime variable only once (unless there are other differences in your queries aside from the DateTime, but i couldn't see any...). Also, in your current code, the very first query (the one before the `if` block), is pointless, or so it seems to me...

Comment: Without more context, it's impossible to know exactly what you want as a suitable answer. But, based on the code you posted, and making the assumption that "don't repeat yourself" is a goal here, one obvious simplification would be to use the `customfiltersetting` to select a specific `Func<T, TResult>`, where `T` is your data element type and `TResult` is `DateTime`. Call that delegate value `selectKey`. ...

Comment: ... Then you just have a single query expression that looks like `from s in Filter.FullData() group s by selectKey(s) into g let count = g.Count() orderby g.Key descending select new { Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count };`

Comment: Yes @PeterDuniho, I am looking for simplification as I am simply made copy paste of the code. Thank you for suggestions. :)

Comment: @blenderfreaky: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code. It is unfortunate that two other SO members are unfamiliar with the clear guidelines for code edits and so approved your edit. But regardless, that edit should never have been approved. You may change whitespace, indentation, etc. but making material changes to the actual _code_ itself is verboten, and for good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring for a moment problems in your code, like the undeclared `strings` variable, and the use of the illegal `0` value as default values for month and day-of-month values for `DateTime`, you might find your code reads a little better like this:

```
Func<MyDataType, DateTime> selectKey;

switch (PublicVariables.customfiltersetting)
{
    case 0:
        goto default;
    case 1:
        selectKey = s => new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, s.Date.Hour, s.Date.Minute, 0);
        break;
    case 2:
        selectKey = s => new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, s.Date.Hour, 0, 0);
        break;
    case 3:
        selectKey = s => new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    case 4:
        selectKey = s => new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    case 5:
        selectKey = s => new DateTime(s.Date.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    default:
        selectKey = s => new DateTime(s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day, s.Date.Hour, s.Date.Minute, s.Date.Second);
        break;
}

var ordering = from s in Filter.FullData()
               group s by selectKey(s) into g
               let count = g.Count()
               orderby g.Key descending
               select new { Date = g.Key, Column = g.Average(s => s.Column), Count = count };
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.